# Getting started with android development

Tags: java, android

I have been windows developer since the beginning, now the current trends dictate that I focus on newer technologies and platforms.

My question is how can get started with android development and can it be done on windows pc with windows 7, if yes what tools do I need.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Setting up your tools :**

1. Install [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) [NOTE : You can choose any IDE but this is the most widely used one for Android development. [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) is another IDE you could try. ]
2. Install [ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) (Android Development Tools) plugin for eclipse (assuming that you did choose to go with eclipse)
3. Update your android tools by using the Android SDK manager
4. (optional) get an Android device for testing you applications as it is not advisable to rely totally on the emulator

**Getting started :**

5. Since you are a Windows developer, you must be fluent with C#, so catching up with Java (in case, you already haven't) shouldn't be much of a trouble
6. Bookmark the [Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/index.html) and never hesitate to check up the documentation when in doubt
7. Have a look at the [sample codes](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) given on the official website
8. You may wish to follow the steps mentioned up [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) as they walk you through the whole process

**Useful Resources :**

9. [Tutorials by Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html)
10. [Video tutorials by thenewboston](http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC2F07DBCDCC01493A&feature=plcp) [ **Note:** This is the one of the best series of Android video tutorials that I have even found, so don't hesitate to download all 200 of the videos. They are really very helpful! ]
11. [Video tutorials by mybringback](http://www.youtube.com/course?list=ECB03EA9545DD188C3&feature=plcp)
12. Answers on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Good luck! May the Droid be with you! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Watch the Lynda.com's Android App Development With Java training, and you will learn it all... You need Eclipse, Android SDK and the ADT plugin.. that is all..

Happy Developing

Answer (score 2):

You should start at http://developer.android.com/index.html.

Download the SDK, read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

visit the developers blog.
download the sdk.
buy an Android device and micro usb cable.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the Android SDK from http://developer.android.com here you can find tutorials as well

You can also download eclipse and the ADT(Android development tools) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). It's mainly based on Java applications, however you can do some android development on it I believe.

Comment: eclipse isn't just for Android. It's mainly for Java development. You can also develope Android applications on other IDE's e.g. IntelliJ