# nice blog to learn android from basics

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i'm beginner to android, i want to know any simple tech tutorial which teaches me basics of android.
Right from installation to complex stuffs in android. I googled lot but just wanted to know if you guys provide me good one which helps me more.

thanks

Comment: Sorry but tutorial recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: This might be helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12442977/1393623. But yeah, tutorial recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the best blog you are looking for http://coderbridge.com, also you can look for developer.android.com which is fair enough to learn android.

Answer (score 1):

This is really the place to start.

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Click on "building your first app" and go from there.
Make sure to read all of the text.